# How can I jquery/validation with two section in a form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

So I have a fairly large form with two different sections. Both sections start off as hidden:

```
<fieldset class="section1" style="display:none">
//...input fields
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="section2" style="display:none">
//...input fields
</fieldset>
```

The sections are shown depending on which radio button the user selects. This all works great until I get to validation. How could I go about validating the form using the jQuery/Validation plugin but have it only validate the section that is showing?

Note: There are other sections that are always shown so I'd rather not have two separate forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could `ignore` validation rules for elements inside the hidden section of your form:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    ignore: 'fieldset:hidden :input',
    ...
});
```

Comment: Simple. Elegant. Worked. Thank you.

Comment: or `ignore: ':not(:visible)'`